# Converting values is not displaying the right result

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have the following code which is supposed to convert Bytes to Kilobytes.

`3434343 bytes = 3353.85 KB`

Code:

```
a = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
double k = Math.round(a/1024*100000)/100000;
et2.setText(String.valueOf(k));
```

That gives the following result:

`3434343 bytes = 3353.0 KB`

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have integer values as intermediates. Use:

```
double k = Math.round(a/1024.0*100000.0)/100000.0;
```

instead.

Comment: That was quick! Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how your answer would change the result? We only would get some rounding errors. Since `a` is a double, the division and multiplication doesn't change anything. Only the division after the round is different. That would result in a rounding error, but not in an error of factor 100?!

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux We're not looking at a factor of 100. We're looking at the post-round truncation,

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) returns a `long`.  Use
[`Math.rint(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint%28double%29)`/ 100000`
or `((double) Math.round(...))/100000`.

[Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29):

> Returns the result of rounding the argument **to an integer**. The result is equivalent to `(long) Math.floor(d+0.5)`.

[Math.rint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint%28double%29):

> Returns **the double conversion** of the result of rounding the argument to an integer. Tie breaks are rounded towards even.